# How to create a table with repeating the parent element values in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a requirement to create a table using JSON data using Jasperstudio 6.2.12 and export it to .xlsx format. I'm able to create the table as shown below:
[image]

The requirement I have is to iterate the values in A, B, C, and D columns based on the number of rows in the E and F columns. The expected output is:
[image]

The JSON data I've used to print the table is :

```
{
"root": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "accounts": [{
            "bank": "LLOYDS",
            "accountNumber": 123456,
            "references": [{
                    "name": "Eva Doe",
                    "refAccountNumber": 6549873

                },
                {
                    "name": "Robin Doe",
                    "refAccountNumber": 3216545

                },
                {
                    "name": "Peter Doe",
                    "refAccountNumber": 9876549

                }
            ]

        }]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "accounts": [{
            "bank": "HSBC",
            "accountNumber": 654321,
            "references": [{
                    "name": "Sam Doe",
                    "refAccountNumber": 6549873

                },
                {
                    "name": "Roger Doe",
                    "refAccountNumber": 3216545

                },
                {
                    "name": "Jason Doe",
                    "refAccountNumber": 9876549

                }
            ]

        }]
    }
]}
```

JRXML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.13.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="accounts" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="066cfa9f-bcf0-4095-8d82-a5ef1cb8632d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Test"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination" value="apply"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.all" value="Accounts"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row" value="1"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.exports.xls.font.size.fix.enabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="maximumRowsPerSheet" value="0"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="AccountsDataset" uuid="73085770-27bc-42cb-b4db-edc97074de2c">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Test"/>
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[root.accounts]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="bank" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="bank"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bank]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="accountNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="accountNumber"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[accountNumber]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="accoutType" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="accoutType"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[accoutType]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="references" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="references"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[references]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="ReferencesDataset" uuid="b23c5f84-b106-4d89-a5d4-6287aa8bbdf7">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Test"/>
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[root.accounts.references]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="refAccountNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="refAccountNumber"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[refAccountNumber]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="MainDataset" uuid="ab297ea1-81e6-4a6f-b90c-4ce1fb9521a2">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Test"/>
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[root]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="firstName"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lastName"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="email" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="email"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[email]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="accounts" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="accounts"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[accounts]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="root" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="root"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[root]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="254" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="480" height="60" uuid="268fe625-e43f-48d5-90c7-f396d09cd88d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="MainDataset" uuid="67830a07-2594-4532-ae34-96829b8046da">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("root")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="a8cf3aa0-1633-4f19-a908-6efbf55d2f75">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="b89609d4-5cbb-4f5b-b470-c9f9f4ad9d26"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="ec954e2c-43e4-43ba-9005-03272b9daad5"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="e7f5cfca-a803-485d-be01-5d2f785fbf0b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="0a2eb2ed-75b9-46c3-8751-871c5473c3e1"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="767b9d15-53e5-4a0b-be8c-ec94fc6398f8"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="c7103510-df1d-4c31-a30f-9b726540dd7a">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="11192151-2c03-4590-91f7-87021b022301"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Bank]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <componentElement>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="8b2678af-1b87-49e6-aca2-af0cec3d7a46"/>
                                <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="AccountsDataset" uuid="faa7fa1c-7169-48fb-aac2-7483a2477998">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("accounts")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="80">
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="97ec29f7-36f2-4ecc-9f30-3049e0648e97"/>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bank}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:listContents>
                                </jr:list>
                            </componentElement>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="5a4bb23a-7d61-486b-91f8-b5150cb85817">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="30680d44-df3b-484e-b059-399e0a21b304"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Account Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <componentElement>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="d7780443-ba11-4d20-944d-4f8210a74506"/>
                                <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="AccountsDataset" uuid="2c245f1d-7a8f-46dc-85c3-737b5b0bc5a1">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("accounts")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="80">
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="ba6b13f3-770d-4a02-b3f0-5d4293393cd3"/>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:listContents>
                                </jr:list>
                            </componentElement>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="0720c554-a0af-4192-a669-38cea560a2e2">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="98adb234-9003-4704-85e4-295538f4273c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Ref Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <componentElement>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="faf83492-91ac-4a39-9483-512d6555c3d3"/>
                                <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="ReferencesDataset" uuid="832a218b-199c-4055-9891-0afaf629bf50">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("accounts.references")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="80">
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="955502f3-afec-40aa-a8f8-b5e83d43bcbc"/>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:listContents>
                                </jr:list>
                            </componentElement>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="2aed257e-00f2-4594-a9ac-9b504262ee3e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="be058bb0-b9f3-4b41-b074-c1f44350eb09"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Ref Account Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <componentElement>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="ed5f0c5e-8f14-4565-8159-b7528e035f3c"/>
                                <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="ReferencesDataset" uuid="2c2d0c12-930c-45c5-a3a1-f8228fc78d7f">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("accounts.references")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="80">
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="59563298-0f0f-4b62-b263-511abb945d1a"/>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{refAccountNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:listContents>
                                </jr:list>
                            </componentElement>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Please help me to iterate the values in A, B, C, and D columns based on the number of rows in the E and F columns and get the expected output. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a single subdataset that has the fields from all levels of the JSON tree.  To do that you'll have to switch to the [JSONQL query executer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html), which allows you to map fields from the parent nodes of the ones selected by the data source.

Once you have all the fields in a single dataset, you can use a simple table to display them.

The report would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.13.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="accounts" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="066cfa9f-bcf0-4095-8d82-a5ef1cb8632d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Test"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination" value="apply"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.all" value="Accounts"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row" value="1"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.exports.xls.font.size.fix.enabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="maximumRowsPerSheet" value="0"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="ReferencesDataset" uuid="b23c5f84-b106-4d89-a5d4-6287aa8bbdf7">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Test"/>
        <queryString language="jsonql">
            <![CDATA[root.accounts.references]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^^^^.firstName"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^^^^.lastName"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="bank" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^^.bank"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bank]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="accountNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^^.accountNumber"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[accountNumber]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="refAccountNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="refAccountNumber"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[refAccountNumber]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="root" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="root"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[root]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="254" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="480" height="60" uuid="268fe625-e43f-48d5-90c7-f396d09cd88d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ReferencesDataset" uuid="67830a07-2594-4532-ae34-96829b8046da">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("root.accounts.references.*")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="a8cf3aa0-1633-4f19-a908-6efbf55d2f75">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="b89609d4-5cbb-4f5b-b470-c9f9f4ad9d26"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="ec954e2c-43e4-43ba-9005-03272b9daad5"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="e7f5cfca-a803-485d-be01-5d2f785fbf0b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="0a2eb2ed-75b9-46c3-8751-871c5473c3e1"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="767b9d15-53e5-4a0b-be8c-ec94fc6398f8"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="c7103510-df1d-4c31-a30f-9b726540dd7a">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="11192151-2c03-4590-91f7-87021b022301"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Bank]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="97ec29f7-36f2-4ecc-9f30-3049e0648e97"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bank}]]></textFieldExpression>
                             </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="5a4bb23a-7d61-486b-91f8-b5150cb85817">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="30680d44-df3b-484e-b059-399e0a21b304"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Account Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                             <textField>
                                 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="ba6b13f3-770d-4a02-b3f0-5d4293393cd3"/>
                                 <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                             </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="0720c554-a0af-4192-a669-38cea560a2e2">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="98adb234-9003-4704-85e4-295538f4273c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Ref Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                             <textField>
                                 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="955502f3-afec-40aa-a8f8-b5e83d43bcbc"/>
                                 <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                             </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="2aed257e-00f2-4594-a9ac-9b504262ee3e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="be058bb0-b9f3-4b41-b074-c1f44350eb09"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Ref Account Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                             <textField>
                                 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="59563298-0f0f-4b62-b263-511abb945d1a"/>
                                 <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{refAccountNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                             </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: It exactly works as per the requirement! Thank you ever so much!!